# while loop stuck using su -c

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

```
while read s p;
do
su $s -c "DISPLAY=:$p javaapp ";
done < <(ps aux | grep /usr/bin/x2goruncommand | awk '{print $1,$13;}')
```

In the above, I am looping through all of my x2go sessions and would like to execute a command so that their sessions start a javaapp.  The while loop works but it will get stuck on the first loop..basically my javaapp will display its starting message and I have to Ctrl-C before it moves on to the next loop.

How can I make it run the entire loop?  I have tried adding & and also > /dev/null but that didn't work.

Comment: i think su will ask for password. you will need expect to do it.

Comment: Where did you add the `&`?  `su` won't exit until the command it runs completes, so you may be able to use `su $s -c "DISPLAY=:$p javaapp &"` (`&` inside double quotes).

Comment: DISPLAY=:$p javaapp &  <--that's what I did inside the quotes.   Didn't work

Comment: does you get prompt back when you run `su $s -c "DISPLAY=:$p javaapp "` individually?